# How to create a break between divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi guys so i have a php function in my database which returns search results back from my database. Everything is working apart from the face i want to get it so that there is a break between each list. So for example each element which is returned should be inside its own border so a square. At the moment all the elements are in one big square, rather than its own square.

Code:

```
            $('#addButton').on('click', function( event ) {
                var searchedValue = $('#search_term').val(); 
                var divHolder = $('.selectedStuff'); 
                divHolder.append(searchedValue + '<br>').css({
                    'background-color': 'yellow',
                    'width': '700px',
                    'margin-top': '50px',
                    'border-style': 'solid',
                    'border-color': '#0000ff'
               });
```

As you can see i have applied the border, however its doing it around everything rather than each element which is returned , so it should look like :

```
 -----------------------------------------------
|                                              |
|       Elment 1                               |
 -----------------------------------------------

 -----------------------------------------------
|                                              |
|       Elment 2                               |
 -----------------------------------------------
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: You are assigning the `.css()` to both the append `searchedValue` and to the `<br>`.  I assume you don't want it to apply to the `<br>`.

Comment: Nah the br was just to try it out etc , but that makes it go below the line and not in a new div

Comment: Wrap your `searchedValue` into it's own div before appending it.

Comment: I thought it was>? would you please illustrate ur answer below? so i can try it out

Comment: `searchedValue` is just text.  There's no wrapping in a div anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what formatting you are trying to achieve, but I'd suggest wrapping your `searchedValue` into its own div so you can format it separately by changing this:

```
            divHolder.append(searchedValue + '<br>').css({
                'background-color': 'yellow',
                'width': '700px',
                'margin-top': '50px',
                'border-style': 'solid',
                'border-color': '#0000ff'
           });
```

to this:

```
            $("<div>" + searchedValue + "</div>").css({
                'background-color': 'yellow',
                'width': '700px',
                'margin-top': '50px',
                'border-style': 'solid',
                'border-color': '#0000ff'
           }).appendTo(divHolder);
```

Comment: Thats fantastic, exactly what i wanted, thank u again